# lower bound on the norm of (correlated) matrix multiplication

Tags: linear-algebra

Suppose $X, U \in \mathbb{R}^{n \times r}$, $n>r$, where $U$ is a fixed matrix and $X$ is a variable, and both are of full column ranks. Let $\mathfrak{R} = \{ \Psi \in \mathbb{R}^{r \times r}: \Psi  \Psi^\top = \Psi^\top \Psi = I_r \}$ be the set of rotation matrices in dimension $r$. Also suppose there exists constants $c_1,c_2 >0$ such that $X$ satisifes:

(a) $\|X\|_2 > c_1$: this implies that $X$ is away from the zero matrix.

(b) $\min_{\Psi \in \mathfrak{R}} \|X-U \Psi\|_F > c_2$: this implies that $X$ is away from $U$ (after the best possible rotation).

$\textbf{Question}$:

Given condition (a) and (b), can we find a constant $c_3 > 0$ (probably in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$) such that the following holds?
\begin{align}
&\|(XX^\top - UU^\top)X\|_F > c_3 
\end{align}

Remark: We have from (b) that $\|XX^\top - UU^\top \|_F > c_4$. You may use this instead of (b). You may also use other norms/singular value conditions in (a) and (b) if that helps.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No, there is no lower bound. Take for $\epsilon\neq 0$ arbitrarily small:
$$ X=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0  \\ 0 & \epsilon \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right)  \ \ \mbox{and} \ \ U=\left( \begin{matrix} 1 & 0 \\ 0 & 1 \\ 0 & 0\end{matrix} \right) .$$
However, if you add a condition on $X^T X$ having a uniformly bounded inverse then your claim is correct.

Let $f(X)=\|(X X^T-U U^T)X\|_F$. 
If we add the constraint 
$\|(X^T X)^{-1}\|\leq M<+\infty$ to the others then we claim that $f$
will have a non-zero lower bound. Suppose the contrary. 
Then we may find a sequence $X_n$ satisfying the
criteria and such that $f(X_n) \rightarrow 0$.
It is easy to see that $X_n$ must be bounded. Using compactness
we may assume that $X_n$ converges to $X$ which therefore verifies:
$$ (X X^T-U U^T)X = 0 .$$ 
Because of our auxilary condition
 $X^T X$ is invertible so
$$ X = U \left(U^T X 
(X^T X)^{-1} \right) \equiv U A$$
with $A$ an $r\times r$ matrix.
Both $X$ and $U$ have  full rank
so $A$ is invertible and then 
$$ U (A A^T-I) U^T X= 0 $$
from which (using again full rank) $I=A A^T$ which contradicts the
condition regarding rotations.

Comment: I forgot to mention that both X and U should be of full column ranks.

Comment: Could you explain a little bit more? Suppose $X^\top X$ has a uniformly bounded inverse, then can you get a generic form of the lower bound $c_3$ in terms of $c_1$ and $c_2$? Thanks.

Comment: I don't think that I am able to calculate explicitly a lower bound from the other constants (at least I don't see how to do so). Only prove that a lower non-zero bound exists if this is of interest?

Comment: That will be of great help, too.

Comment: Actually, the exact conditions I have are (a) $\|X\|_2 > \|U\|_2/2$, (b) $\min_{\Psi \in \mathfrak{R}} \|X-U \Psi\|_F > \sigma_r (U)/8$, where $\sigma_r (U)$ is the $r$-th singular value of $U$. Then can I get $\|(XX^\top - UU^\top)X\|_F > c_3 \times$ some norm/measure of $U$ for some constant $c3 >0$? You may use other norms/measures on the R.H.S. of (a), (b) and the result term. Do you think it is possible to get such a result? Otherwise, the existence of a non-zero lower bound is also great.

Comment: I think my counter example verifies your precise conditions (for $\epsilon$ small), so it seems you need further conditions on $X$ to prevent it from 'ĺoosing' maximal rank (like the one I add to my post)

Comment: The solution is intriguing. Could you explain a bit what might the barrier to get a concrete lower bound? What if I have (a) $\sigma_r(X) > \|U\|_2/2$ ($r$-th singular value of $X$), (b) $\sigma_r(X-U\Psi) > \|U\|_2/8$ ($\Psi$ is the best rotation) or $\sigma_r(XX^\top - UU^\top) > c_2 \|U\|_2$, then is it possible to get a concrete $c_3$ (maybe in terms of $\|U\|_2$ or $\sigma_r(U)$)? From simulations of randomly generating X and U satisfying conditions above, it seems there exists a nontrivial bound (I performs $10^9$ independent trials). It will be great if you can shed some light on this.

Comment: The mechanism is the (approximate) loss of rank. Then $XX^T-UU^T$ may have a non-trivial (approx) kernel and $X$  (approx) maps the space into that kernel, like for the example. Imposing a non-zero lower bound for the $r$'th singular value of either $X$ (+rotation condition)  or $XX^T-UU^T$  prevents this from happening so they are both ok. I'll think about concrete bounds.

Comment: @leo Haven't got much further in getting concrete bounds but here are some possibly useful considerations: Using $|\cdot|_2$ norm rather than Frobenius might help as we may use orthogonality. You may then write $X$ as $PX+(1-P)X$ where $P$ is the orthogonal projection onto the image of $U$. The two-norm then splits up into two parts: one along the image of $U$ and the other orthogonal to it. For the first you may again write $PX=UA$ for some invertible $r$ by $r$ matrix as in my example and try to fiddle with this... But calculations did not turn out easy for me. Good luck!